# How to enable PHP5 module using Puppet Apache2 module

Tags: php, puppet

I am using this Apache2 handling Puppet module

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache

When I execute the following code, it successfully installs the virtual host, but it never enables the PHP5 module for Apache2. How do I enable it?

```
class { 'apache': 
    mpm_module => 'prefork',
}

apache::vhost { 'mysite':
    ...
    xyz
    ...
}

apache::mod { 'php5': }
```

I also tried to replace the line with:

```
apache::mod { 'php': }
```

but that didn't help. The php5 module doesn't get enabled. I have to enable it manually by running `a2enmod php5`. The documentation doesn't say much about this. Thanks!

Comment: This is a question for Server Fault.

Comment: You're right. I forgot. Is there a way to transfer it there? I don't think I can delete the question here.

Comment: I'm a server admin who uses puppet frequently, and personally I use the same vhost module you are but I also use a php module in combination with it, and assign my web server nodes to use that module in combination with the apache one. There are lots of ways to accomplish what you want though, especially if you are using package-based installs.

Comment: Ah, can you please let me know which php module you're using? I might just go with that.

Comment: this thias guy makes a lot of great modules, this is the specific one I use: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/thias/php

Comment: Perfect. Unless someone posts a solution that directly involves the apache2 module, I will use your workaround. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If five people with 3000 rep or more vote to close your question, with it flagged to go to server fault, then it will be moved automatically. The only other way to move a question is for a moderator to do it. I've voted to close/move already.

Comment: Will it reopen for more comments on Server Fault?

Comment: I'll wait if someone posts a solution that's not a workaround. If nothing shows up until tomorrow, I'll turn skrilled's answer to an actual answer. And thanks for educating me about how this works.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem, how do you enable mod_php with the apache module from http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache

Comment: See the answer below. This works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the [README](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/README.md#defined-type-apachemod), the `apache::mod` type should only be used for modules that do not have a specific `apache::mod::` class. This is not true for PHP, see another part of the same [README](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/README.md#class-apachemodphp). Therefor, the correct manifest would be

```
include apache::mod::php
```

These semi-official Puppet Labs modules are generally a good resource.

Comment: That's it. Thanks Felix! I couldn't figure this out myself from the docs.